# Weird function about Array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have the following peace of code:

```
const reducedValue = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (decision(curr)){
        return acc++;
    }
    return acc;
}, 0);
```

when `console.log(samApples)` is always `0`, even when the `decision` is `true` several times. However when I change to `acc += 1` woks fine.

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `++` operator if used after the variable (`Y++` - postfix) returns the value, and then increments it. If used before the value (`++Y` - prefix), it increments, and then returns it:

```js
let x = 1, y = 1;

console.log(x++); // returns x then increments

console.log(++y); // increments y and then returns it
```

However, you don't need to increment the accumulator, return the new value instead:

```
const reducedValue = array.reduce((acc, curr) => 
  acc + (decision(curr) ? 1 : 0)
, 0);
```

And since you can cast a boolean to a number using the unary `+` operator, you can shorten it to:

```
const reducedValue = array.reduce((acc, curr) => 
  acc + decision(curr) // acc + +decision(curr) in typescript
, 0);
```

Comment: `acc + decision(curr)` suffices.

Comment: Yep. I'm used to typescript (explicit casting).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of how the `++` operator works. When you do `x++` `x` is incremented AFTER you current operation, which in your case is `return` and since primitive types are passed as value instead of as reference as arguments to functions, the increment is processed after the `return` and not carried over to the next iteration.

On contrary `+=` are carried out immediately and thus BEFORE any other operation. Hence why this works. If you however prefer to use the `++` syntax, use it like this: `++x`, since this operation is carried out BEFORE the `return` (and woks exactly like `+= 1`).

---

Also check out this (arguably better) description on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#description

---

And a little proof of concept:

```js
const val = [1,2,3,4,5,6].reduce((acc, curr) => {
   return ++acc;
}, 0);

console.log(val)
```